# What is the energy density of the zero Higgs field in SI units?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs

Higgs boson has a mass, and a [vacuum expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_expectation_value), both are in electronvolts.

An uncommon feature of the Higgs field is that to its zero energy density belongs a non-zero field value.

Is it possible, probably with QFT, to calculate its energy density (per unit volume)? In layman terms, how would it work?

Comment: As you said, it has *zero* energy density, so why are you asking how to calculate the energy density? And, as you said, the field has a *nonzero* VEV, so why does your title refer to the “zero Higgs field”?

Comment: @G.Smith If I understood that maxican hat thing well, I understand the origin in that potential diagram. Maybe I formulated something badly? Effectively, I am asking for, how high is the origin in the mexican hat potential. In SI units. Feel free to edit the post, if it makes it better.

Comment: Aha. I understand your question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Mexican hat" Higgs potential is

$$V(H)=\lambda(|H|^2-v^2)^2$$

where $v$ is the Higgs vacuum expectation value, 246 GeV, and the dimensionless Higgs coupling $\lambda$ is about 0.0323.

To get this value for $\lambda$, look at the quadratic "mass term" when expanding the Higgs field around its VEV, $H=v+h$. It is $4\lambda v^2 h^2$, so the mass of the Higgs is $m_H^2=8\lambda v^2$ and thus $\lambda=m_H^2/8v^2$. Using 125 GeV as the measured Higgs mass, one gets $\lambda\approx 125^2/(8\times 246^2)$.

When the Higgs field $H$ is zero, the potential is $\lambda v^4$, which is about $1.18\times 10^8\text{ GeV}^4$. The conversion for energy density between natural units and SI units is

$$1\text{ GeV}^4\approx 2.08\times10^{37}\text{ J/m}^3$$

so the zero-Higgs-field energy density is about $2.45\times 10^{45}\text{ J/m}^3$. The corresponds to a mass density of $2.72\times 10^{28}\text{ kg/m}^3$. This is about 10 orders of magnitude higher than density at the center of a neutron star, but about 68 orders of magnitude lower than the Planck density.

Note that this energy density is not the Higgs energy density now, when $H=v$. That energy density is, as you said, zero.

Comment: @Cham Thanks for catching that typo!

Comment: It feels a bit weird that the Higgs mass $m_H \approx 125~\mathrm{GeV}$ is almost exactly half the Higgs vacuum expectation value.

Comment: Agreed. I don’t think there is an accepted explanation for that.

Comment: @Cham:  It boils down to the fact that $\lambda \approx 1/32$, but that may not be a sufficient explanation.

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks! Wiki says, neutron star central density is only about $10^{17} \frac{\rm{kg}}{\rm m^3}$. Thus, the difference is only 9 orders of magnitude.

Comment: @peterh Thanks for catching this error.

Comment: @G.Smith, Actually you should be talking about $V(H)=\lambda(|H|^2-v^2)^2 + V_0$ with an arbitrary non-zero $V_0$. We don't have the means in QFT to calculate the the absolute value of $V(H)$ (well, you can infer the value from the gravitational effect though). In other words, we can only calculate how the Higgs VEV shifts the energy, but  not the absolute value of $V(H)$, unless you conjure up a symmetry to exclude $V_0$.

Comment: @MadMax I am using the evidence that the gravitational effect is tiny.

Comment: *This is about 10 orders of magnitude higher than density at the center of a neutron star* - For less, they impaled to Michelson and Morley- :P