# Is there any possibility of manipulating the Higgs field, and if so, what effects would we see?

Tags: standard-model, vacuum, higgs, symmetry-breaking

These are questions asked from a perspective of "what if" according to current theory. If the Higgs field is the source of mass for (most) elementary particles, and the unique property of this field is that its VEV is above zero, what would be the effects of quieting the Higgs field to create a true vacuum? Could matter still exist in a region where the VEV was zero, or lower than the measured magnitude of the Higgs field? Could we use such a region as a form of propulsion without emitting electo-magnetic radiation?

Comment: Related: [What is the energy density of the zero Higgs field in SI units?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506020/)

Comment: We manipulate the Higgs field very slightly when we create a Higgs boson.

Comment: What would be the effects on particles traveling through such a region? Could we imagine a bubble of lowered VEV and could it be moved arround?

Comment: @G. Smith : However, that's sort of like creating a photon - an electromagnetic wave. What you are making is a "Higgs wave". What the OP is asking about is something more like the Higgs field analogue of a static electric and/or magnetic field. Is there such an analogue for the Higgs field, and if not, why not (because its particle equivalent has a lot of mass? because of the propensity of the particles to decay?)?