# Can the density of a black hole exceed the density of the Higgs field?

Tags: standard-model

In [a different Stack Exchange answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/506048/311307), the mass-energy density of the Higgs field is said to be $2.45\times 10^{45}\text{ J/m}^3$. Furthermore, the answer says that "This is about 10 orders of magnitude higher than density at the center of a neutron star, but about 68 orders of magnitude lower than the Planck density.".

My understanding is that some particles have mass because they couple with the Higgs field and "borrow" mass-energy from it. If this understanding is correct, then it would not be possible for the mass density of any region of space, including the core of a black hole, to exceed the mass-energy density of the Higgs field, right?

Comment: That’s not the energy density of the Higgs field *now*.

Comment: "they couple with the Higgs field and "borrow" mass-energy from it." is hand waving description of the early universe, but not wrong. But " the core of a black hole, " needs a general relativity mathematical model, and cannot be described by the standard model of particle physics mechanisms (including the Higgs field), as yet. There is no quantization of gravity model and in general relativity metrics, there is no core.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common misconception that the Higgs field is the only source of mass. The Higgs field is responsible for the masses of the fundamental particles, and as you say these particles get their masses by interacting with the Higgs field, however the particle masses make up only a small part of the mass in the universe.

This happens because energy counts as mass too, using Einstein's famous equation $E = mc^2$. The classic example of this is that the masses of the three up and down valence quarks in a proton make up only $1\%$ of the mass of the proton. The other $99\%$ comes from the interaction energy of the quarks and is unrelated to the Higgs field. This means the Higgs field places no limit on the densities that matter can achieve in the universe.

The final point we should make clear, is that the Higgs field is unusual in that its energy density is not zero when the field is zero and only falls to zero when the field has a non-zero value (its [vacuum expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_expectation_value) or *VEV*). As we look around us today the Higgs field energy density is zero, and to get to the energy density you mention we'd have to heat the universe up the the [electroweak transition temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_scale), which is so high we can achieve this only fleetingly in our biggest collider the LHC.

So the bottom line is that the Higgs field imposes no limit on the densities matter can reach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the 99% of the proton mass, you are referring to gluons, right? I've read that gluons are massless, similar to photons. So how does mass arise in general, if not only from the Higgs field? It can't be the case that all energy has mass, because photons have energy but no mass, right?

Comment: In bound states the energy does contribute a mass given by E = mc². A free photon does not have a mass, but a hypothetical bound state of photons called a [kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)) would have a mass and indeed could form a black hole.